# Индикация рисков с помощью машинного обучения

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, анализ-данных

Есть задача : **выявление рисков в системе оценки качества образования**. У каждого риска есть вероятность (**очень низкая, низкая, средняя, высокая**) и последствие риска (**нет последствий, малые, средние, большие, критические последствия**). По этим двум свойствам можна дать качественную оценку риску. Например, если последствия риска критические но вероятность очень низкая, то по этому риску можно не принимать никаких действий. Но если последствия риска критические и вероятность высокая, то нужно принимать какие-то действия.

Примерный список рисков:

- Недостаточное финансирование образовательной деятельности
- Недостаточный набор абитуриентов
- Недостаточное обеспечение уровня качества образовательных услуг
- и т.п.

И есть Google Forms, где есть вопросы, которые задают для студентов / преподавателей / администрация. Вопросы с ответом типа **"Полностью согласен" / "Скорее согласен" / "Трудно ответить" / "Скорее не согласен" / "Полностью не согласен"**. Каждый вопрос отвечает за какой-то риск. Например если есть риск X, то у него есть подмножество вопросов, которые влияют на уровень риска. На основе ответов на эти вопросы можно вычислить уровень риска по текущей выборке.

Есть ответы каждой из этих групп, да и сгенерировать их легко. Сейчас уровень риска определяется простыми математическими формулами.

В чем проблема: **нужно к этой системе приделать машинное обучение**. Вообще любое, так чтобы было и чтобы оно что-то делало, ну чтобы можно было о этом написать типа "для прогнозирования чего-то там использовали что-то там". Я в машинном обучении и анализе данных полный новичок и даже не знаю что и как можно в этой ситуации прогнозировать. Поэтому хочу спросить совета у знающих как это можно провернуть, не решение, а просто идеи что можно прогнозировать и каким методом. Такая система вроде называется risk assessment, но научные статьи по внедрению машинного обучения в такие системы, к сожалению, ничего мне не дали.

Заранее благодарен за любой совет и наводку, который подскажет в каком направлении двигаться!

Answer (score 0):

> Сейчас уровень риска определяется простыми математическими формулами.

Вот и возьмите те штуки, которые участвуют в формулах, в качестве "фич". Я так понимаю, каждый вид риска считается отдельно, ну вот и заполните табличку, где будут эти "фичи" и значение целевой переменной - величина риска. А потом возьмите, например, обычную линейную регрессию, и примените её к фичам и целевой переменной.

Но, скорее всего, если всё уже считается формулами, то, возможно, машинное обучение вам и не поможет никак, получатся в итоге те же самые формулы. Но вам сейчас главное начать вообще вникать в тему. Почитайте про линейную регрессию для начала. Это по сути подбор коэффициентов для формулы вычисления целевой переменной по разным параметрам (фичам).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Смотрел на счёт линейной регрессии эти дни и хотелось бы узнать можно ли что-то сложнее здесь использовать?
А вот если сделать из этого задачу классификации? У нас есть данные о ответах пользователей и есть риски. Но мы не знаем какие вопросы влияют на какие риски. Можно ли использовать какой-то метод классификации для того, чтобы определить какой вопрос на какой риск влияет. например на входе у нас ответы одного студента, а на выходе что-то типа {risk1=0.6, risk2=0.2, risk3=0, risk4=1} (где числовые значения определяют уровень вероятности риска).

Comment: @nazarstick Классификацию можно, но она обычно применяется для дискретных, неранжированных значений. А для значений типа как у вас риск от 0 до 1 со всеми промежуточными значениями известно что 0<0.1<...<0.9<1 лучше применять всё же регрессию. Модели, которые сразу много целевых переменных считают обычно сложнее, если вы прямо такое сразу хотите, то вам нужно смотреть в сторону нейросетей, у них можно на выходе и сразу несколько значений иметь, именно как вы хотите, не вопрос. Посмотрите библиотеку `Keras`, там всё довольно просто. Главное разобраться с размерностью входов и выходов нейросети.

Comment: Просто если вы ну совсем не в теме, я бы советовал вам всё же начать с азов и с простых моделей, иначе вы будете воспринимать это всё как волшебный чёрный ящик, совершенно не понимая, как это работает и насколько получаемым результатам вообще можно верить. А нейросеть в общем-то и есть чёрный ящик, устройство которого довольно сложно интерпретировать и превратить обратно в формулы. В отличие от линейной регрессии.